# Check for entries before processing

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys!
I have a script that should add images into the database. It does that. The only problem is that it does not only adds new images but also adds existing ones.
Im sure its a really simple task for you, for me its too much!

So again this code should check if an entry exists and then add the image if it does not exists.
Thank you :)

```
    <?php

include('mysql.php');

if ($handle = opendir('images')) {

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if($file!='.' && $file!='..') {
            $images[] = "('".$file."')";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO images (filename) VALUES ".implode(',', $images)." ";
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
    print mysql_error();
}
else {
    print "finished installing your images!";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `filename` field unique (`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX filename_idx ON images (filename)`) then simply replace `INSERT INTO images` with `INSERT IGNORE INTO images`.

As an added bonus, you'll now also have the `filename` field indexed, which will speed up `SELECT`s by `filename`.

Comment: hey my friend, thank you for your time, this seems to work :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add `filename` as unique key in your database.

Or, you could use this php script:

```
$exists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images 
   WHERE filename LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($images[0])."%'");
if(mysql_num_rows($exists == 0)){
  $query = "INSERT INTO images (filename) VALUES ".implode(',', $images)." ";
  if (!mysql_query($query)) {
    print mysql_error();
  }
  else {
    print "finished installing your images!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. To check if exiting filenames are already stored in the database you must do the following:

- retrieve filenames from the database
- check if current file is between them

PS: You should **require** your mysql.php file, without it, the rest of your script won't work.

```
<?php
require_once('mysql.php');

$existing_files = array();
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM images WHERE 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
    array_push($existing_files, $row['filename']);
}


if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if($file!='.' && $file!='..' && !in_array($file, $existing_files)) {
            $images[] = "('".$file."')";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO images (filename) VALUES ".implode(',', $images)." ";
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
    print mysql_error();
}
else {
    print "finished installing your images!";
}
```

Comment: hey Bogdan, thank you for your detailed answer! I took this code but get this response: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in .../install_images.php on line 21
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 any suggestions?

Comment: @Gerald you should check what your `$images` contains after the loop thru the directory, just before the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do an md5sum on the file, and use that for uniqueness, then do a select to see if the file is there, if it isn't insert if it it and return the id as the approve state, or if it already exists the id of the existing record.  Doing it by filename is fine, unless, several people are uploading the same file but named differently.  The downside to doing this is if the files are big, then it takes some of your resources to do this.